# Recommended way to lock down internet to only specific applications within ubuntu-variant installation?

Tags: security, internet, application

Trying to axe extra connections - ex: visualstudiocode wants to send some junk, and instead of going through the clunky settings there, I just wanna strip it of internet access except when I may want to. Any recommendations? I believe ages ago I saw someone show a command to container-ize just an executable for subset resources? Seems like if the symlinks or permissions were right it would be doable on linux?

Thanks!

Edit: Ideally I can just run a terminal command to disable/enable access to the internet when opening the application - or have two icons..

Edit 2: Reason for this, is I want to use the internet, but not have my editors or other non-essential applications taking up resources.

Comment: Try linux capabilities 'setcap 'cap_net_raw-p' your_executable' or configure apparmor

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Install Visual studio code from flathub, and use Flatseal to block it's access to the network whenever you want.
2. Use VSCodium instead, it is the open source build of VSCode (no telemetry and other proprietary stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Try linux capabilities

```
setcap 'cap_net_raw-p' your_executable
```

or configure apparmor

https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-block-internet-access-for-an-application/